# Blue screen of Death on Install

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation, bsod

I have a machine with Windows Vista Installed.

It has an Intel X25 SSD as the System Drive

I want to reinstall (I plan to format and overwrite Vista) with XP.

When I boot up using the Dell XP CD it loads the initial drivers then i get a Blue Screen.  This is quite concerning.  The installed OS works ok, but its giving problems so I want to remove it.

- Should I just format the SSD and try again?  Will this make any difference?
- Can I do something to avoid hitting the Blue Screen?
- Its possible I had corrupt sectors on one of the other disks, will a new XP install use the System drive or drive 0?
- Can I force the install to use a specific drive when installing?

Error:

```
*** STOP: 0x0000007B (0xF78D2524,0x0000034,0x00000000,0x00000000)
```

---

I never did find the answer, however

- I removed the SSD and tried to install on other disk - CRASH
- I disconnected the other disk and tried to install with only SSD plugged in - CRASH
- I removed 1 block of RAM - CRASH
- I used a windows 7 CD - NO CRASH

Comment: what does the blue screen say? The error code could provide some insight as to why you are getting it which will help lead to a positive course of action, otherwise, we'd all just be guessing at how to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the Dell *CD* is giving you a blue screen before even starting to install to HDD, then it has nothing to do with the HDD. It might be a bad CD burn or bad CD driver or something.
2. Reformatting the SDD is unlikely to help, but you can try it.
3. Instead of trying to reinstall your entire operating system when you don't understand why it is "giving a problem", why not ask your REAL question, i.e. the actual problem you're having, rather than using antiquated, unsupported software (that is, Windows XP)?

Comment: I used a Windows 7 CD and the problem went away :) looks like answer 3 was right all along :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late: But do you have AHCI enabled? You really want it enabled when installing to a SSD and it even yields better performance when using a regular HDD. But XP is to old to handle AHCI without exttra drivers.

If that is the case: Press F6 during setup and insert the right driver in the old fashioned floppy drive (the real one, or one of the four hardcoded working USB ones) - Did I already mention that XP is **OLD** ?

Comment: I solved it by installing Windows 7 (I looked a bit harder for the CD).  Don't think it was an SSD issue though because it still happened when I disconnected the SSD.  I dont have a working floppy on the PC.  Did I mention that Floppy Drives are OLD! Thanks for your input.

Comment: Aye. Floppy drives are old. So is XP. When XP was relative new old fashioned 34 pin connected floppy drives where still common. And AHCI was non existent. When I combine a new PC with AHCI enabled and an unpatched XP (Even with SP3) it will blue screen unless: 1) I load the AHCI driver via an old fashioned floppy. 2) I load the AHCI driver via on of 4 specific USB floppy drives. 3) I turn AHCI off (you do not want this!)  4) I slipstream drivers into the windows XP install disk (google slipstream and nlite).   Moot points now that you found the win7 DVD, but nice as future reference.